# How to update <%=Convert.ToString() %> using update panel in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to update the test variable through ajax & C# backend code. I have set test variable as string builder in .cs file & want to update the value of the same variable through .cs code using ajax while clicking on div tag.

Code in .aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upre" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <%=Convert.ToString(test) %>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ajax code:

```
 $(".mb-2").click(function (e) {
      $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "one.aspx/Subscribe",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: '{"name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}',
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (msg) {
                   if (msg.d) {
                       alert(msg.d);
                    }
                 },
                 error: function (req, status, error) {
                   alert("Error try again");
                 }
             });

     return false;
 });
```

Backend Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Subscribe(string name, string email)
{
    AllApps abc = new AllApps();
    abc.iPriceFrom = 50;
    abc.iPriceTo = 100;
    abc.test();`enter code here`
    return "thanks " + name + ", your email " + email + " is subscribed to our newsletter.";
}
```

I tried with the above code but it is not updating the variable value at the front side. Data is updating from backend (.cs) file. I want to update the test variable through ajax & C# backend code. I have set test variable as string builder in .cs file & want to update the value of the same variable through .cs code using ajax while clicking on div tag.

Comment: It is not possible. What you can do is trigger update panel by using [`AsyncPostBackTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers#the-triggers-element)

Comment: I already tried with asyncpostbacktrigger but for that, we need server-side control to update. I want to update the div variable.

Comment: you can update the text from the client side, e.g. when your ajax-success-handler gets called.

Comment: Yes, that is the one way. I already tried with the same and it's working. Thanks